# Why is PyMongo aggregate taking a long time?

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, pymongo

When I use aggregate in `pymongo` it takes approximately 4-5 seconds.
But when I use MongoDB Atlas UI to query the same thing, it takes only 0.01 - 0.07 seconds.

Why is my python pymongo aggregate query so slow?

#### My Analyzed Query Performance

```
{
    'stages': 
    [
        { 
            '$_internalSearchMongotRemote': 
            { 
                'mongotQuery': 
                { 
                    'index': 'default', 
                    'text': 
                    { 
                        'query': 'knowivate developers', 
                        'path': 
                        { 
                            'wildcard': '*' 
                        } 
                    } 
                }, 
                'explain': 
                { 
                    'type': 'BooleanQuery', 
                    'args': 
                    { 'must': [], 
                    'mustNot': [], 
                    'should': 
                    [
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'title', 
                                'value': 'developers' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'website', 
                                'value': 'developers' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'domain', 
                                'value': 'knowivate' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'url', 'value': 'developers' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'website', 'value': 'knowivate' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'meta_description', 'value': 'developers' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'p', 'value': 'knowivate' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'url', 'value': 'knowivate' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'meta_description', 'value': 'knowivate' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'title', 'value': 'knowivate' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'domain', 'value': 'developers' 
                            } 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            'type': 'TermQuery', 
                            'args': 
                            { 
                                'path': 'p', 'value': 'developers' 
                            } 
                        }
                    ], 
                        'filter': [], 
                        'minimumShouldMatch': 0 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }, 
        { 
            '$_internalSearchIdLookup': {} 
        }, 
        { 
            '$limit': 10 
        }, 
        { 
            '$project': 
            { 
                'url': True, 'title': True, 
                'type': True, 'website': True, 
                'meta_description': True, 
                '_id': False 
            } 
        }

    ], 

    'serverInfo': 
    { 
        'host': 'mtm-aws-apsosdddfas51-0-m0-18-shard-00-01-c67kj.mongodb.net', 
        'port': 27000, 'version': '4.4.10', 
        'gitVersion': '58971da1ef93435a9f62bf4708a82313def6e88c' 
    }, 
    'ok': 1.0, 
    '$clusterTime': 
    { 
        'clusterTime': Timestamp(1637762646, 4), 
        'signature': 
        { 
            'hash': b'\xee\x32g\t:(QI\x9e%i\xdd\xc1k+\xa2\xc\xa!\r', 
            'keyId': 6993066431563064065 
        } 
    }, 
    'operationTime': Timestamp(1637762646, 4) 
}
```

My query:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv:/ajority")
db = client["db"]
query = [{
    '$search': {
    'index': 'default',
    'text': {
        'query': 'knowivate developers',
        'path': {
        'wildcard': '*'
    }}}},
    {"$limit" : 10}]

results = list(db["collection_name"].aggregate(query))

# analyze query
print(db.command('aggregate', 'collection_name', pipeline=query, explain=True))
```

**PS**

1. I created index using Mongodb UI > Search Indexes
2. When I view Indexes there are no indexes.

Comment: There are so many considerations, and you have provided so little.  Your connection string is malformed, but I suspect that is for security reasons.  It may be helpful to elaborate on that.  The Analyzed Query Performance.  Super hard to read in its current form.  Would be helpful if you formatted it to make it easier to read.  Also, this format does not seem familiar, how did you generate the analyzed query performance?  My main questions are - when comparing the explain plan between the two methods, how do they differ?

Comment: do you have the same data size on Atlas and On-prem Databases ?
How did you define the index on the Atlas side, and on-prem side ?  (show screenshot from the UI if you cant find the index definition)

Comment: @barrypicker Now I added more data.

Comment: I would compare by running the profiler on both the pyMongo and the UI to see what the differences are.